# Chocolatey install when program is already install on windows

Tags: chocolatey

I'm changing to use Chocolatey more an more  on my windows 10 laptop.

If I have already install eg Visual Studio Code the "normal from windows" what is the outcome if a later install it with "choco install vscode" ?

Comment: See [Is there a way to convert a non-Chocolatey installed program into a Chocolatey installed one?](https://superuser.com/questions/789190/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-non-chocolatey-installed-program-into-a-chocolatey-i)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is... it depends.

Since most Chocolatey packages are just wrappers around the native installer for an application, the question becomes, what happens if you try to install an application that is already installed.  In most cases, a sensible installer will simply say "application already installed" and move on.  In these situations, Chocolatey will normally handle this via the `validExitCodes` property that a package maintainer will have configured.  But this is not guaranteed.

Best advice would be to try it.  If you are at all unsure, you could uninstall the existing application, and install with Chocolatey.

Or, you could try using the `-n` option for the uninstall command, [documented here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install#options-and-switches)

> -n, --skippowershell, --skip-powershell, --skipscripts, --skip-scripts, --skip-automation-scripts
>
> Skip Powershell - Do not run chocolateyInstall.ps1. Defaults to false.

There are other packages that do "other" things, so regardless of what you choose to do, I would advice looking at the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file for a package, to understand what it is trying to do.